# What should one do if a close relative doesn't pay back the borrowed money on the deadline?

Tags: fiqh

I've lent some money to a close relative of mine and I noticed he didn't pay back other family members too so what kind of punishment can I give him? Can I harm so bad that he breaks his leg or nose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to know the rule of Islam before giving to any thing to anyone

- Have two witness  (min)
- Write down the transaction
- Take the signature of all the people (witnesses, lender, borrower)

If you would had all these, there would not be any problem.

Your next question: Can I harm him, break the leg or nose :) :)

It is Better to involve other relatives and make pressure on him or forgive him, because by breaking his leg or nose you are not going to get anything except something bad....

Comment: Well I have a witness because it was all written down on a pc. But that witness is a stranger and my close relative lives a pretty far away. I can't believe he did it to his younger brother, I hate him for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive him if you can afford to ot wait till he can afford to,  and do not try to barter one of his child for the loaned money, it is an un Islamic tradition.

Comment: How long should I wait? Because his behaviour is repeating itself over and over again.